# How should the phrase "in question" be translated into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I want to translate the phrase **"in question"** into Latin, as in:

> Please deposit the car keys next to the car **in question**, and then leave by the main door.

How would I express this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a comparable expression in Latin.
The most idiomatic option seems to be using pronouns.
For "the car in question" I would suggest:

- *raeda*
- *ea raeda*
- *eadem raeda*
- *ipsa raeda*
- *illa raeda*
- *raeda cita/citata*
- *raeda praedicta*

The best choice depends on what kind of emphasis you need.
If you want to underline that it is the very same car and not another one, *eadem raeda* is a clear choice.
If you want to say "the mentioned car", then using a participle like *cita* or *citata* sounds best.
Or you could go with *praedicta*, which is quite literally "said before".

Perhaps the closest analogue to "the car in question" is indeed *raeda praedicta*.

Comment: And in the case of written communication *vid.sup.* or *vide supra,* hints at a superior ride.

Answer (score 4):

This is often a fluff phrase in English that need not be translated at all:

> Ubi raedam conductam rettulisti, velimus clavem juxta **raedam** deponas.
> *When you have returned your rental car, we ask that you deposit the key next to the car.*

… because, what other car could we be talking about?

If that should not be clear enough, you can probably use *ille*:

> Si aliquam raedam emere vis, juxta **illam raedam** depone clavem.
> *If you want to buy a car, deposit the key next to **that car**.*

(Strange way to go about it, but what do I know.)

If by “in question” you mean “aforementioned,” you can say *quem/quam/quod dixi/commemoravi* or *de quo/qua mentionem feci* (or *fecimus* and so on).

Comment: I know that **"de quo"** (as well as "de qua") is used in modern Italian to express something close to the English phrase "in question". It's also a phrase in legalese. Does "de quo" have the same meaning in Latin?

Comment: @TomHosker It does not. To my knowledge *de quo* by itself has no particular meaning.

Comment: So [Oxford Reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195369380.001.0001/acref-9780195369380-e-527) states that the literal translation of "de quo" is "of which", which seems close enough that it could be translated as "in question" in the right context. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @TomHosker Let's say the point where I don't follow is where it "seems close enough" to you. It would be ungrammatical nonsense in English ("put the key next to the car of which"), and I believe it is the same in Latin.

Comment: @TomHosker I agree with Sebastian. It is similar to how *status quo* does not make much sense in Latin in isolation, but this part of a Latin phrase has obtained a meaning in other languages. I suppose *de quo* ("of which") is part of *de quo locutus sum* ("of which I have spoken") or some such expression, and in Latin you'd have to use it in full.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Okay. I understand now. Thank you.